# Can we infect our system by opening a email with outlook 2016?

Tags: email, phishing, outlook

I read that it is possible to get a virus just by opening a mail (not even clicking at any links on it or opening the attachments), because scripts can be attached to it.

Is this also true for Outlook 2016? Is scripting activated by default?

I am using Version 1811

Comment: Do you consider 0day exploits in-scope?

Comment: No, I consider regular known attacks.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, no, maybe.

On any given day, the right answer will be one of the three. Generally the right solution to the problem is considered to be assuming that you may be vulnerable and applying mitigation (firewalls, anti-malware & backups are the essential ones).